# Removing a debit card from apple wallet

Tags: ios, apple-pay, wallet

I have a debit card in apple wallet that I no longer use. The card has actually been deactivated by my bank because I requested a new card.

When I attempt to add the new card I get an error, ‘invalid card’. I’m certain I typed in everything correctly.

I try to remove the old card first but I do not see it anywhere in wallet until I attempt to add a new card.

How do I delete the old card from apple wallet if I do not see it in the wallet?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to remove a card from the Wallet (based on iOS 12):

1. Go to `Settings -> Wallet & Apple Pay`.
2. Under `Payment Cards`, tap on the card you want to remove.
3. Tap on `Info` button (at the top).
4. Scroll to the bottom and tap `Remove Card`.
   [image: Apple Wallet Card Image]

That will remove the card from your payment options and Wallet.  More info can be found on [this Apple Support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205583).

Comment: My card isn’t showing under payment cards.

Comment: @brewpixels Have you tried removing the card from within the Wallet itself?  Open Wallet directly (not thru the lock screen shortcut), scroll to the bottom of all the cards until you 'Edit Passes'.  From there you should be able to remove cards.

Comment: Doesn’t work either. Only card I see is the Apple Pay card. I press the plus button, then the continue button, then I see my old card and it ask me for the security code. Under all this I click ‘add another card’, and it fails from there. I called the bank and they said everything was fine on their end, strange.

Comment: Those are the only 2 ways to add/remove cards.  You should contact Apple Support.